# Set version property without using @Version annotation of MongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

We are using Spring.data.mongodb's @Version annotation for making use of optimistic locking and save entities using `mongoTemplate.save(T entity)`.

As we're using a Hexagonal architecture, in which the concrete `MongoTemplate` implementation is located in an infrastructure module and the domain model is located within a "core" module, we needed to put a maven dependency towards spring.data.mongodb in there as well, in order to use the `@Version` annotation:

```
@Document("basket")
public class Basket {


  @Id
  BasketId id;

  @Version
  long documentVersion;

}
```

Now we want to get rid of the Spring dependencies in the whole `core` module, as we want to extract `core` as a LIB-jar and using it in another project (that doesn't use spring). For the `@Document` and `@Id` part here that is easy, because `MongoTemplate` appears to have no pain to detect our `BasketId` (because it's called "id") and MongoTemplate offers to provide a collection name when getting rid of `@Document`. However, this is false for `documentVersion` and simply renaming it to `version` does not work either.

So I am wondering to make use of the version property without using the annotation with MongoTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself after digging in. I decommissioned the usage of `org.springframework.data.annotation.@Version` whatsoever in the `core` project and replaced it with my own annotation called `@EnabledOptimisticLocking`. In order to make `spring.data.mongodb` watch out for it instead of `@Version` you need to do the following:

```
public class CustomVersionAnnotationMappingContext extends MongoMappingContext {

private static final FieldNamingStrategy DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY = PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE;

private FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy = DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY;

@Override
public MongoPersistentProperty createPersistentProperty(Property property, BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> owner,
        SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder) {
    return new CustomVersionAnnotationPersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, fieldNamingStrategy);
}

@Override
public void setFieldNamingStrategy(FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy) {
    super.setFieldNamingStrategy(fieldNamingStrategy);
    this.fieldNamingStrategy = fieldNamingStrategy == null ? DEFAULT_NAMING_STRATEGY : fieldNamingStrategy;
}

class CustomVersionAnnotationPersistentProperty extends CachingMongoPersistentProperty {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link CachingMongoPersistentProperty}.
     *
     * @param property
     * @param owner
     * @param simpleTypeHolder
     * @param fieldNamingStrategy
     */
    public CustomVersionAnnotationPersistentProperty(Property property,
            MongoPersistentEntity<?> owner,
            SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder,
            FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy) {
        super(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, fieldNamingStrategy);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isVersionProperty() {
        return isAnnotationPresent(EnableOptimisticLocking.class);
    }
}
}
```

And then simply initialize it as a bean prior to the default one that would be created otherwise:

```
@Bean
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext(@Autowired CustomConversions customConversions) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new CustomVersionAnnotationMappingContext();
    mappingContext.setSimpleTypeHolder(customConversions.getSimpleTypeHolder());
    mappingContext.setAutoIndexCreation(true);
    mappingContext.afterPropertiesSet();

    return mappingContext;
}
```

Unfortunately the fieldNamingStrategy class attribute is private and there's no getter for it, therefore it is needed to pull that field up and dupliate it.

Theoretically it is now possible to replace other annotations with your own as well if needed, such as `@Id`.